# VBA: Why isn't variable working in named range?

Tags: vba, excel

This is part of a larger code, but this snippet isn't working. I'm trying to just set two cells equal to each other, but it's not working. When I use the .Range("v1_copy"), the code runs, but when I name that range and place it as a variable (myCopyRange), the code doesn't run and I get the error: Compile error: Method or data member not found. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub copy_paste_test()

Dim myCopyRange As Range
Dim myPasteRange As Range
Dim myWS1 As Worksheet
Dim myWS2 As Worksheet

Set myWS1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myWS2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

myCopyRange = Range("v1_copy")
myPasteRange = Range("v1_paste")

'myWS2.Range("v1_paste").Value = myWS1.Range("v1_copy").Value
' This line works, but the below line doesn't
 myWS2.myPasteRange.Value = myWS1.myCopyRange.Value
' This should be the exact same, just substituting the variable, but doesn't work

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `Set` keyword for your `Range` object reference assignments to `myCopyRange` and `myPasteRange`.

But for retrieving a named range, the best place to go if you want fully explicit code that *does what it says and says what it does*, is to dereference the `Name` from the appropriate `Names` collection.

If the names are workbook-scoped, qualify with a `Workbook` object - here a `book` object variable, but depending on needs `ActiveWorkbook` or `ThisWorkbook` work just as well:

```
Set myRange = book.Names("name").RefersToRange
```

If the names are worksheet-scoped, qualify with a `Worksheet` object - here a `sheet` object variable, but `ActiveSheet` works just as well:

```
Set myRange = sheet.Names("name").RefersToRange
```

That way the code won't break if the workbook is renamed, or if the user changes the "tab name" of the sheet. It won't break as long as the name exists in the queried `Names` collection.

---

> ```
> 'myWS2.Range("v1_paste").Value = myWS1.Range("v1_copy").Value
> ' This line works, but the below line doesn't
>  myWS2.myPasteRange.Value = myWS1.myCopyRange.Value
> ' This should be the exact same, just substituting the variable, but doesn't work
> ```

*This should be the exact same* - no. `myWS1.myCopyRange` is illegal: `myWS1` is a `Worksheet` object: the `Worksheet` interface doesn't have a `myCopyRange` member, hence *method or data member not found*.

Since `myCopyRange` is a `Range` object, it knows about its `Parent` which is the `Worksheet` it belongs to: there's no need to qualify it... and there's no need to dereference it again either - this is enough:

```
myPasteRange.Value = myCopyRange.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Range will only apply to the currently active worksheet unless you add the Worksheet reference at the time of assignment (not at the time usage as you have done).

Since you are access a different worksheet, your second assignment will fail.

```
myCopyRange = myWS1.Range("v1_copy") 
myPasteRange = myPasteRange = Range("v1_paste")
```

See the [Range Object Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel):

> When it's used without an object qualifier (an object to the left of
>   the period), the Range property returns a range on the active sheet
>   ... Use the Activate method to activate a worksheet before you use the
>   Range property without an explicit object qualifier

If you are trying to refer to [NamedRanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-named-ranges) and not a name held in a VBA variable, you need to change the way you are accessing the range.

Workbook-scope NamedRanges do not use worksheet reference - since they don't apply to a worksheet, they apply at the workbook level. If you need to add a qualifier, you add the workbook:

```
Range("MyBook.xls!MyRange")
```

If you are referring to Worksheet-scope NamedRange, you need a qualifier, but it goes inside the quotations:

```
Range("Sheet1!Sales")
```

Comment: The catch is that unqualified `Range` becomes a member call against `Me` if the code is copied from a standard/class module and then pasted into a `Worksheet` module: unqualified `Range`, `Names`, `Cells`, `Rows`, and `Columns` calls are just too context-dependent to be unambiguous. Better write explicit code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Properly create ranges by using `Set` and don't refer to worksheets before them. Workbook-scoped ranges don't need to be tied to any worksheet.

```
Sub copy_paste_test()

    Dim myCopyRange As Range
    Dim myPasteRange As Range

    Set myCopyRange = Range("v1_copy")
    Set myPasteRange = Range("v1_paste")

    Range("v1_paste").Value = Range("v1_copy").Value
    'myPasteRange.Value = myCopyRange.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: *Workbook-scoped* named ranges don't need to be tied to any worksheet.